# Call to a member function query() on null in /var/www/html/mvc/models/Anuncios.php:9

Tags: php

podem me ajudar com esse erro?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null
>   in /var/www/html/mvc/models/Anuncios.php:9 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/mvc/controllers/homeController.php(10):
>   Anuncios->getQuantidade() #1 /var/www/html/mvc/core/Core.php(37):
>   homeController->index() #2 /var/www/html/mvc/index.php(20):
>   Core->run() #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/mvc/models/Anuncios.php
>   on line 9

Anuncios.php

```
<?php
class Anuncios extends model
{
    public function getQuantidade()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as quantidade FROM epi";
        $sql = $this->db->query($sql);

        if ($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
            $sql = $sql->fetch();
            return $sql['quantidade'];
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

config.php

```
<?php
require_once 'environment.php';
$config = array();

if (ENVIRONMENT == "development") {
    define("BASE_URL", "http://localhost/mvc/");
    $config['host'] = 'localhost';
    $config['dbname'] = 'self_epi';
    $config['dbuser'] = 'root';
    $config['dbpass'] = '32051217';
} else {
    //define("BASE_URL", "http://www.site.com.br");
    $config['host'] = 'localhost';
    $config['dbname'] = 'selfepi';
    $config['dbuser'] = 'root';
    $config['dbpass'] = 'Admin';
}
global $db;
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$config['dbname'].";host=".$config['host'], $config['dbuser'], $config['dbpass']);
    echo 'conectou';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Erro: ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

model.php

```
<?php
class model
{
    protected $db;
    public funciton __construct()
    {
        global $db;
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

controller

```
<?php

class homeController extends controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $anuncios = new Anuncios();
        $usuarios = new Usuarios();
        $dados = array(
            'quantidade' => $anuncios->getQuantidade(),
            'nome' => $usuarios->getNome(),
            'idade' => $usuarios->getIdade()
        );
        $this->loadTemplate('home',$dados);
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Helder, evite colocar imagens de código, coloque o próprio código em texto na pergunta e formate usando o botão **{}**

Comment: olá Helder, favor postar também o código do homeController.

Comment: O que está tentando fazer? Quando ocorre o erro? Utiliza alguma biblioteca/framework?

Comment: Estou fazendo um projeto em mvc, quando tento retornar os dados do banco dá esse erro na função query(), acredito que o arquivo não esteja conseguindo usar a variável $db de conexão

Answer (score 1, accepted):

coloca um `global $db;`  e ver se pega

Comment: já está como global no arquivo config.php

Comment: mas acho que você precisa adicionar um global dentro das chaves não? eu pelo menos faço assim e não dá problema algum

Answer (score 0):

Olá Helder tente trocar o nome da variável que recebe a query, talvez esteja dando conflito pois você está declarando a mesma variável($sql) por duas vezes.

```
$res = $this->db->query($sql);
if ($res->rowCount() > 0) {
        $sql = $res->fetch();
        return $sql['quantidade'];
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
```